# SQLAlchemy : How to inherit a data from other model and set it to default?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm still not used to `SQLAlchemy` so it might be dumb question.
I'm trying to make web app first time using `Flask` and `SQLAlchemy`.
What I want to do is inherit a data from other model and set it to default.

What I was doing is something like this

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    upload_photo = db.relationship('Photo', backref='user')

class Photo(db.Model):
        uploader_name = db.Column(db.String(64), db.ForeignKey('user.username'))
```

So I want to set the username who uploaded the photo to the uploader_name.
But when I referred to uploder_name, it is always `'None'`.
Maybe I misunderstand about relationship and ForeignKeys.
How can I fix this? Also please tell me how wrong my way is and how to use relationship correctly.

Thanks for replying. But the output is still same even though I changed like the answer.What I was doing is like this
Actually I want to show it on webpage but I cannot refer even though other things can be refered.

```
    photos = Photo.query.with_entities(Photo.name, Photo.image, Photo.user).all()
    return render_template('index.html', title='Home', photos=photos)
```

and HTML is like this

```
    {% for photo in photos %}
            {{ photo.user.username }}
    {% endfor %}
```

For this, it shows nothing and when I changed this to `{{ photo.user }}`, it shows `None`

I show model part just in case

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    photos = db.relationship('Photo', back_populates='user')

class Photo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user = db.relationship('User', back_populates='photos')
```

I checked how it works on interpreter but it's same.

Comment: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#building-a-relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use relationships for that (in this case, [One-To-Many](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many)):

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    photos = db.relationship('Photo', back_populates = 'user')


class Photo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user = db.relationship('User', back_populates = 'photos')
```

Then you can access these object on both sides:

```
user = User.query.filter_by(id = 1).first()
user.photos #  Outputs all photos with user_id set to this user

photo = Photo.query.filter_by(id = 1).first()
photo.user #  Outputs the user of a certain photo
```

You can add photos to a using in different ways, the most straight forward would be:

```
user = User.query.filter_by(id = 1).first()
new_photo = Photo() 
user.photos.append(new_photo)
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: `db.ForeignKey('user.username')` should probably be `db.ForeignKey('user.id')`, since `user_id` has integer type.

Comment: fixed the code... sorry for the mistakes... this should definitely work. are you getting any errors?

Comment: I didn't get any errors but the output is still 'None'.
I will edit my question soon.

Comment: The original uploader_name line must change like yours?
The original one is Sting and user.username though.

Comment: yes... because you can access the username by using `photo.user.username`

Comment: I canged it like yours but it's actually still 'None'.
I will show you what I am doing soon.

Comment: I checked on interpreter but the output is nothing as well

Comment: How are you creating and adding the data to your database??

Comment: I deleted db file and migrations folder and venv folder and reset all.
But it's still same.

Comment: I recommend you double check all the links posted here ([this](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#building-a-relationship) and [this](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many)), and see if you get your head around relationships... I also though it was weird at first, but now they come easily for me!